# how to use antd in electron react boilerplate?

Tags: reactjs, electron, antd

I created a project using electron react boilerplate
https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate
Everything works, but I decided to add antd (ant design)

```sh
yarn add antd
```

Then I import the antd styles

index.tsx

```
...
import "./styles/global.css";
import "./styles/fonts.css";

import "antd/dist/antd.css"
...
```

Next I used a button of type primary

some_component.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import s from './someComponent.module.scss'
import { Button } from "antd";

export const SomeComponent: React.FC = () => {
  return <div className={s.root}>
    <Button type={'primary'}> button text </Button>
  </div>
}
```

But the style of the button remains the same (with standard styles)

I tried importing the component styles directly into my global.css, also tried adding to the component style, but that didn't change anything

```css
@import "~antd/dist/antd.css";
```

I have looked into the following repository where it works, however I didn’t figure out how to add it to my project. I don't want to use this repository as it works crookedly and doesn't use typescript

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this import in App.global.css or create new one custom.global.scss

copy this line

```
@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';
```

then import this scss into your App.tsx

```
import './custom.global.scss';
```

This should work